# Exporting sass/css in npm module - Rollup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, create-react-app, rollupjs

**Overview**
I'm trying to write a react based npm module. I've configured my environment using rollup and I can see the js/d.ts/css files being created in the build.

**Issue**
Using npm link, I was testing in a separate project. Now I'm able to import the js file, but I'm unable to import the css file.
Here is my rollup configuration (`rollup.config.js`)

```
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass';
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default {
  input: "src/index.tsx",
  output: [{
      file: pkg.main,
      format: "cjs",
      exports: "named",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: "es",
      exports: "named",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.scss', '.css']
    }),
    sass({
      output: "autocomplete_style.css"
    }),
    typescript({
      rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
      exclude: "**/__tests__/**",
      clean: true
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: ["node_modules/**"],
      namedExports: {
        "node_modules/react/react.js": [
          "Children",
          "Component",
          "PropTypes",
          "createElement"
        ],
        "node_modules/react-dom/index.js": ["render"]
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

Please note, I'm able to create a successful build. The issue is just with the import of the generated css file.

Comment: Could you show how you are importing the css? A sample file of where the import occurs would help.